# Date parse exception

Tags: date

I'm trying to parse this date and getting an exception. What is not correct about this?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String sDate  = "2024-01-05";   // Trying to format to date 05-Jan-2024

Date date1 = dateFormat1.parse(sDate);
```

Comment: There should be a 7 day ban for questions related to an exception or error that don't share the actual exception. (I joke, but please share the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String sDate  = "2024-01-05";   // Trying to format to date 05-Jan-2024
Date date1 = dateFormat1.parse(sDate);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date1));
```

Comment: that worked thanks, didn't know I needed a double parse.